# Android Inapp billing - Play Store keeps sending PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I have implemented inapp billing in my app some time ago, so it's not the v3 API, but the v2.
When I try to buy an unmanaged item I get charged and everything goes fine, my app then shows a dialog indicating that the purchase did well.
The problem is that Google Play keeps sending again this

```
01-29 12:30:40.805: I/BillingService(18895): Received action: com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE
01-29 12:30:40.805: I/BillingService(18895): checkResponseCode got requestId: 8646305544958370499
01-29 12:30:40.805: I/BillingService(18895): checkResponseCode got responseCode: RESULT_OK
01-29 12:30:40.805: I/BillingService(18895): Received action: com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED

01-29 12:30:41.155: I/BillingService(18895): Received action: com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE
01-29 12:30:41.155: I/BillingService(18895): checkResponseCode got requestId: 2207507822000358335
01-29 12:30:41.155: I/BillingService(18895): checkResponseCode got responseCode: RESULT_OK
```

So my dialog is showed 6-7 times, it looks like it add one more time every try i do.
I really don't understand it. Can someone explain why to me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you already have item simply ignore it? Also did you send CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS back?

Comment: No i didn't is it necessary?
Sorry for my ignorance i'm new to inapp billing

Comment: Check the docs, but IIRC it will keep resending until you acknowledge you received. The Dungeons samples does this, compare to your code.